# Android development - Access JSON within fragment - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new with android development. I am using TABLayout and I am having a problem getting information from the JSON data set inside a fragment.

Inside the fragment, I implement an AsyncTask that is evoked inside the fragment’s method onCreate.

In doInBackground I save the JSON data in an object (eventsDetail) that is public for the fragment class.

Inside of onCreateView I use eventsDetail to populate various string widgets. Also, I populate longitude and latitude data to a map (SupportMapFragment).

When I first enter at onCreateView I have no issues. Then I leave the fragment. When I go back into the fragment again, I receive the error (java.lang.NullPointerException) on the eventsDetail object.

Has anyone encountered this problem? I think the problem is that I am accessing the JSON incorrectly.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code and the stack trace from the logs.

Comment: You are more than likely getting a NullPointerException because you don't understand that AsyncTask doesn't immediately return a result that you are trying to use.

Comment: try executing stuff in onPostExecute method ,,,,this avoids problems by great extent